# Learning Redux, does this violate any state principals?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an axios call to DELETE and POST my api, and it wasn't rerendering after the calls were fulfilled. It turned out it was because those calls didn't return a new list of objects with the object removed or added. To fix this I put this into my code

Delete:

```
  case "DELETE_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
    return {
      ...state,
      userTripReports: state.userTripReports.filter(tripReport => tripReport !== action.response), // Filters the deleted trip report out of userTripReports
    }
  }
```

Post:

```
  case "POST_TRIP_REPORTS_FULFILLED": {
    return {
      ...state,
      userTripReports: state.userTripReports.reverse().concat(action.response).reverse() // The new trip report must be concatted into the first position
    }
  }
```

Does this violate any state mutability principals?

Comment: `.reverse()` directly mutates the Array, which is something you shouldn't do. You could do `[...state.userTripReports].reverse()...`. However, `.filter()` returns a new Array so this is completely acceptable. To prove mutation check `const a = [1,2,3,4,5]; a.reverse(); console.log(a)`.

Comment: why does redux not throw an error when you mutate the state?

Comment: Mutating state isn't an error, just something that is not advised.